# ModuleNotFoundError at / No module named 'punctuator.punc'; 'punctuator' is not a package - Heroku,aws , django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku

I am getting this error in aws elastic beanstalk also.

So my django app works fine locally and it gets deployed also. However when I try to access my site via the code I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 959, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>

During handling of the above exception (module 'punctuator' has no attribute '__path__'), another exception occurred:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 100, in _get_response
    resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 544, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 588, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 48, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 581, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
    <source code not available>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
    <source code not available>
  File "/app/qaudious/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from transcribe_audio.views import( upload_page, local_page, drive_page,home_view,)
  File "/app/transcribe_audio/views.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import tasks
  File "/app/transcribe_audio/tasks.py", line 3, in <module>
    from punctuator import Punctuator
  File "/app/.heroku/python/bin/punctuator.py", line 5, in <module>
    from punctuator.punc import command_line_runner

Exception Type: ModuleNotFoundError at /
Exception Value: No module named 'punctuator.punc'; 'punctuator' is not a package
```

I have already included punctuator==0.9.6 in my requirements.txt file.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: It appears that some other `punctuator` than the one you expect is being imported here. Do you have any module or file named `punctuator`?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat, Thanks for replying. No I don't have any other file named punctuator. 
Error is in the below file according to the message and I don't know where that file is.
/app/.heroku/python/bin/punctuator.py in <module>

Comment: Ah looking at that `/app/.heroku/python/bin/punctuator.py` this file itself is named `punctuator` yet it is trying to import the package and ends up importing itself giving you an error.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat So what should I do? I can't find that file in my local machine.
I am sorry I am really new at this!!

Comment: @SWATIPANDEY All you need to do is to rename the file. You can rename it as punctuator2.py. It will work.